# How do i output the logs from log file instead of application log

Tags: reactjs, docker, logging, containers

I have a React application in Docker, while using Docker logs command it shows the output log like this which is application log

> NODE_ENV=production node ./build/server/index.js
>
> 2019-08-23T09:49:58.127Z - info: Application logs file: /root/.application.log
>   Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
>   designed for a production environment, as it will leak
>   memory, and will not scale past a single process.
>   2019-08-23T09:49:58.192Z - info: HTTP server is now running on http://localhost:8080

I am writing the actual log to a file called ui.log

> 06:51:32.021 INFO  time="2019-08-23T06:51:32.021Z"

how to forward this log into docker logs?

I tried this command `RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /app/ui.log`  in Dockerfile

but its still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use entry point for that purpose but one thing keeps in mind that in this case, the `npm` processes will be running in the background and tailing log file will be the root process `tail -f /root/applog.log`.

Which is not recommended in the production system but you can take advantage in development.

```
FROM node:alpine

COPY  . /root
WORKDIR /root
RUN echo $'#!/bin/sh \n\
npm run start & \n\
sleep 2 # give testServer time to create the newest log \n\
exec tail -f /root/applog.log ' >> /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

That entrypoint starts up npm in the background and then runs the tail with an exec. The exec replaces pid 1 so that signals are passed through.

You can look further [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout) to deal with PID of tail but do not forget to check comment of first answer which is not working in you case.

But in the context of Docker it good for nothing to write log to file, As docker is supposed to run and terminate, not to keep you logs file.

Another thing, for example, if you take AWS [fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) where there is you  do  not need to manage server to run container so you will never be reached to that file, so in that case writing log to file will never help you.

I will suggest writing all logs to console logs in the context of Docker.

Here is a tutorial that you can follow in nodejs to deal with logs.

[winston-logging-tutorial](https://stackify.com/winston-logging-tutorial/)  and [using-winston-a-versatile-logging-library-for-node-js](https://thisdavej.com/using-winston-a-versatile-logging-library-for-node-js/)